# Should I make Enterprise Library Data Block Database object static?

Tags: enterprise-library

Can anyone clarify if Enterprise Library's Database object can be made static without any thread-safety issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an `Database` instance is thread-safe. It is just a big factory spitting out new objects like connections. The instance itself doesn't change state after it is created. When you look at the source code you can see this clearly. The objects it produces are of course not thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to make sure of it.

Comment: How would we go about making sure the objects it produces, such as the parameter or command object is thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

You can, but there's no significant reason to. Database instances are cheap to create and don't hold any  state.

Comment: Yeah, but I want the whole domain library to use only one common database

Answer (score 0):

No don't do it. I tried it and was sorry that I did. While it was thread safe it slowed down my query requests from a web app dramatically. I thought I was being smart skirting the creation of metadata but it gummed things up instead. Now I provide a brand new instance every request and it's as happy and as fast as can be.

Comment: I haven't experienced any of the sort but, to be fair, I haven't had the opportunity to test it on a large scale project either. Are you sure the Database object was the cause of the slowdown?

Comment: I had it as a static property of my static db provider class. Maybe another way works but it does seem people are leaning towards recreating the context every request (Webwise anyway). It worked enough to think it was okay. It failed when you made several quick requests.